# Need to split return JSON string so i can loop JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

in my `JSON` i get a string back:

```
selectedDays: "Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat"
```

I need to break this down so that i can add some form of `loop` to add a `class` but i have no idea how to do this.

is so i can add something like the blow in the `loop`

```
$('button[name=SOME_NAME]).addClass('.btn-primary');
```

Cant figure it out, never used `JSON` data before.

Full data returned in `console.log`

```
{
    endTime: "01:02",
    endTimeHr: "01",
    endTimeMin: "02",
    number: "00000001",
    position: "1",
    selectedDates: "All days of the month",
    selectedDays: "Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat",
    selectedMonths: "Jan, Aug",
    startTime: "01:01",
    startTimeHr: "01",
    startTimeMin: "01",
    timeRange: "-w",
    timeType: "specificTime"
};
```

**Current HTML For Day Buttons**

```
<div class="form-horizontal" id="selectWeekdaysSection">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-lg-4">
            <button id="mon" name="weekdaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Mon">Mon</button>
            <button id="tue" name="weekdaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Tue">Tue</button>
            <button id="wed" name="weekdaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Wed">Wed</button>
            <button id="thur" name="weekdaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Thur">Thur</button>
            <button id="fri" name="weekdaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Fri">Fri</button>
            <button id="sat" name="weekenddaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Sat">Sat</button>
            <button id="sun" name="weekenddaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Sun">Sun</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Screenshot - The blue is the buttons im after applying the style too**
[image]

Comment: It would be good if you would tell us what our HTML is, and to which element(s) you want to add a class, how this depends on the days, and show the desired result. Also please provide the JSON in text format, ... as JSON. What you have at the start of the question is not JSON. At least it lacks braces.

Comment: Do you want to add class to 6 buttons named Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, and Sat for this case? I am asking this because I am so confused even after I read the question more than 3 times now.

Comment: @holydragon Yeh that what i'm after doing

Comment: first things first, `selectedDays: "Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat"` isn't valid JSON

Comment: Like how people want more details and as i'm trying to update it, you downgrade it and try closing it.  Give a chance add more details as request please

Comment: Blums answer is correct. I would just like to add that you can avoid the string manipulations if the JSON string would be `"selectedDays":["Mon","Tue",...]` so that parsing the JSON string already gives you an array you can loop over. Same with a value like `"All days of the month"`. The string has no meaning unless you code it, so if you have control over the format of the data, make it easy on yourself and format the JSON string is such a way that parsing it already gives you something easy to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**STEPS:**

1. Extract the desired data from the JSON.
2. Make the string into the format you are using, which is lowercase without spaces.
3. Split the string into array.
4. Loop through the array and use each string as button id for the selector.
5. Add the class to each of them.

```js
const json = {
  selectedDays: "Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat"
}
let selectedDays = json.selectedDays.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '').split(',')
selectedDays.forEach(day => {
  $('button#' + day).addClass('.btn-primary')
})
// Log the classes
$('button').each((i, e) => {
  console.log($(e).attr('id'), $(e).attr('class'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mon" name="weekdaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Mon">Mon</button>
<button id="tue" name="weekdaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Tue">Tue</button>
<button id="wed" name="weekdaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Wed">Wed</button>
<button id="thur" name="weekdaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Thur">Thur</button>
<button id="fri" name="weekdaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Fri">Fri</button>
<button id="sat" name="weekenddaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Sat">Sat</button>
<button id="sun" name="weekenddaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Sun">Sun</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you'll need to do if you haven't already is to [parse the JSON data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) so you can use it as a JavaScript object. After that you should be able to reference the `selectedDays` property and use JavaScript's [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) string manipulation method to turn the data into something iterable with [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)